# Join 3 tables returns too many results

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables: `users`, `posts`, `videos`. The last 2 tables have `user_id` that associate with `users.id` (first table).

The problem is that when I try to run inner join query and return all posts and videos that have user_id and exists in both tables, I get multiple same records.

```
select * from `users`   
inner join `videos` on `users`.`id` = `videos`.`user_id`   
inner join `posts` on `users`.`id` = `posts`.`user_id`   
where `users`.`id` = ?   
limit 50 offset 0
```

If I run the queries separately, I get 6 rows and 8 rows but with the join I get 48 rows.

Comment: Well, `6 x 8 = 48`. That's expected when you do a cartesian product.

Comment: Ok, so my method is wrong? how do i get total of 14 rows? because all I want is all rows with user_id = X from 2 tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 14 rows in the result (6+8), you need to use `UNION` of the two queries you already have.  Just take care for both to have the same number of columns (and same datatypes in the respective columns.)

It will be something like:

```
SELECT u.*,                              -- list of wanted columns from the users table
       'Video'     AS type
       v.id        AS item_id,           -- and the videos table
       v.posted_at AS posted_datetime  
FROM users AS u 
  INNER JOIN videos AS v 
    ON u.id = v.user_id
WHERE u.id = ?  

UNION ALL

SELECT u.*, 
       'Post'      AS type
       p.id        AS item_id,           -- and the posts table
       p.posted_at AS posted_datetime  
FROM users AS u 
  INNER JOIN posts AS p 
    ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE u.id = ?

ORDER BY posted_datetime                 -- ORDER BY some_column
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0 ;
```